# Disabled/Enabled button base on selected option doesn't work

Tags: angular, select

I dont know what am I doing wrong I am trying to enable button after selecting an option in select, but in another component. I have two component. Component A and component B. The component A has a select with options and in the Component B I have a button. I would like to enable button when select is given. The folder structure looks:
app
components
- component A
- component B

Component A:

```
   <select (change)="onSelectChange($event.target.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let item of method(element.title); trackBy: trackByFn" [value]="item.id">{{item.price}}</option></select>

onSelectChange(value: number) { 
     this.myService.setSelectedValue(value); 
}
```

myService:

```
private selectedValue: number;

setSelectedValue(value: number) {
      this.selectedValue = value;
    }
  
 getSelectedValue() {
      return this.selectedValue;
    }
```

Component B:

```
isButtonEnabled = false;

ngOnInit() { 
    this.isButtonEnabled = this.myService.getSelectedValue() !== undefined; 
}
html: 
<button [ngClass]="{'disabled': !isButtonEnabled}" [disabled]="!isButtonEnabled">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

i will use observable and subscribe using Asyncpipe

Component A

```
onSelectChange(value: number) { 
     this.myService.setSelectedValue(value); 
}
```

myService:

```
private selectedValue: BehaviorSubject<number|null> = new BehaviorSubject<number|null>(null);
selectedValue$ = this.selectedValue.asObservable();
setSelectedValue(value:number) {
this.selectedValue.next(value);
}
```

Component B

```
  constructor(public myService:MyService) {}
<button [class.disabled]="!(myService.selectedValue$| async) " [disabled]="!(myService.selectedValue$ | async)">Click me</button>
```

if you dont need the actual value of number in myservice you can make the type of BehaviorSubject boolean with default false

myService:

```
private selectedValue: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
selectedValue$ = this.selectedValue.asObservable();
setSelectedValue(value:number) {
selectedValue.next(true);
}
```

Comment: Yes it works but conversely. The button is disable when you select an option.

Comment: anyway you are welcome